# "You gonna" vs "you're gonna."

Tags: word-choice, colloquial-language

Is "you're gonna" or "you gonna" more common in colloquial English?

Examples:

> "You/You're gonna sleep?"
>
> "You/You're gonna ruin the mood."
>
> You/You're gonna try to convince me to come back.

Google Books shows both usages (*you're gonna* has more results). However, *you gonna* sounds more natural to me. But I'm not sure because I'm not a native speaker of English.

Comment: Note that "wanna", "gonna" etc. are not used in writing except as direct quotes to indicate how someone spoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the usage "you are," "You're gonna" is more common. "You gonna" is not unheard of but it's pretty sloppy. Note that in some situations, like ebonics, "you gonna" is considered perfectly natural if not grammatical.

The more casual the situation, the more you gonna hear "you gonna."

Note also that these two words, "you" and "you're" sound similar. You gonna find situations where you or a third party says "you're" but it's enunciated more like "you" and this should be understood implicitly; it was "you're."